# What is the Proper Way of Importing Modules in Modular Programming in Python?

Tags: python, module, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

What are the proper ways of importing external packages for modular programming in Python?
Any helpful documents such as a [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/) or [Structuring in Python](http://intermediate-and-advanced-software-carpentry.readthedocs.io/en/latest/structuring-python.html) out there?

#### In Details

I am new to package development in Python (or other languages) and I want to know how the pros do it, i.e. what is the pythonic way, keeping efficiency, readability, and development in mind (e.g. the IDE/Sublime would recognize internal components of that package).

For instance, let's say there is a module that needs `numpy.log`. Should I `import numpy as np` inside the module, or in `__init__.py`? Should I just write `from numpy import log`? Should I write a `common_imports.py` module and `from common_imports import *` in all modules that I write?

Comment: See PEP-8, specifically the [import section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports)

Comment: @metatoaster, I read PEP-8, helpful, thanks. They suggested importing each package in each module without much justification. Is it really efficient to important an entire package?

Comment: When calling `import`, no matter what (e.g. `import os.path` or `from os.path import join`), the entire source file (or the bytecode file) is read by the Python interpreter before it can be parsed to return the module or the single function/object/class that was to be imported.

Comment: Also, having a common_imports module and then `from common_imports import *` in every file will result in additional references to objects/modules that may not be used inside that particular module, and this reference will very slightly increase memory consumption.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, you can import the module however you want. All you need to do is to set the `__all__` variable at module level. It consists of a tuple of names that you want to expose to everyone. For example, if you have a `__init__.py` in package `somepackage`

```
#__init__.py
__all__=('func_a',)

def func_a(): pass
def func_b(): pass
def func_c(): pass
def func_d(): pass
```

Then when you do `from somepackage import *`, only `func_a` will be imported. Also, if you do `from somepackage import func_b`, then Python's gonna throw you an `ImportError`

Comment: Thanks pkqxdd, but this is not what I am asking.  Please see my example under "In Details".

Comment: @Miladiouss What I'm saying is, you can use any way you proposed, as long as you set the `__all__` variable.

Comment: The easiest way is to import whatever you need at the top of each file you have, which is how most python modules do it. If you are still not sure, you can checkout the source codes of some popular pure-python modules, such as `django`.

Comment: That import statement `from somepackage import func_b` is not going to throw an `ImportError`, because `func_b` is defined in the module; `__all__` does not stop an import from happening, it only specifies what gets globbed by the `*` import.